# Are questions about writing OpenType rules on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

Writing OpenType rules for a font is, in my mind, a form of programming. One specifies various sets of rules for glyph substitution, positioning, etc. Often the rules need to be in a specific order. To me, it is akin to writing a logic program in Prolog.

However, it's certainly not procedural programming, so I'm not sure about it being on-topic for SO. I can see how others might not see it as akin to any kind of programming; that such questions would be about using a piece of software rather than about writing software and thus off-topic for SO.

I guess I can just post a question and see what happens, but I thought I'd ask here first whether such questions are appropriate.

Comment: You should be fine, there's a tag and a search of "opentype" in the Stack-search-bar yields 3000+ questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opentype , [search-results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opentype)

Comment: @Coffee There's 80 questions, not 3,000+.  That said, none are closed as off topic, so that seems to indicate people don't have a problem with them.

Comment: I thought my eyes were playing tricks on me @Servy

Comment: @Coffee - Yes, I saw that and should have mentioned it in my question. However, all the questions I saw (but I certainly didn't look at all of them) were about using OpenType fonts, not about creating them.

Comment: @Coffee - Well, now I've found at least [one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952862/developing-coptic-font-in-unicode) about creating a font. It has no answers but does have a comment "This is not the kind of question Stackoverflow is for, but..."

Comment: @TedHopp -  I see where you're coming from, that it's not in the vein of C and Java... Up to you though

Comment: If that's programming then setting your house thermostat is a form of programming as well.  Just make sure it is tagged [thermostat] and not [java] so nobody gets their underwear in a bundle.

Comment: @HansPassant - Could you explain this comment? If you're saying that declarative programming is not programming, then are all questions about html/css off-topic as well? (I, for one, see no essential difference between html code and OpenType rules. The latter is just another way—more arcane, I'll grant you—of specifying a complex data structure.) Or are you trying to make a different point?

Comment: @TedHopp I think Hans Passant meant that if you tag it in such a way that it is generally seen by very targeted audience than noone will start fight with you about it (just guess)... SO may be just a wrong place to get answers for such questions - I believe there is very small number of people who create fonts and I doubt many are on SO.

Comment: @TedHopp on question you've found - it looks more like tool search, so it makes it bad fit for SO in current form...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Thanks; that interpretation of Hans's comment makes sense (although the way I read it, it sounded rather dismissive of writing OpenType rules as programming). I'm afraid that you are right and even if the question is on-topic I'm unlikely to get any answers here. Regarding that other question: it's not clear to me that OP is asking about another tool (perhaps so) but rather how to generate a font that correctly positions combining marks in Coptic scripts.